# list indices must be integers or slices, not str & the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Tags: python, json

In the following code I'm creating a function intended to return the order ID of a trade from Binance. I am receiving all of the trade data in JSON form but when I try use json.loads to access the data using python I get the following two errors...

1. list indices must be integers or slices, not str
2. the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

The code follows...

```
def fetch_order_ID(symbol):
    open_stop_loss = client.get_open_orders(symbol = symbol)
    json_message = json.loads(open_stop_loss)
    order_ID = json_message['orderId']
    print(order_ID)
    
fetch_order_ID(TRADE_SYMBOL)
```

the JSON message...

```
[{'clientOrderId': 'web_f90baa98950a471485d5f4ab387d495d',
  'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000',
  'executedQty': '0.00000000',
  'icebergQty': '0.00000000',
  'isWorking': True,
  'orderId': 1623049977,
  'orderListId': -1,
  'origQty': '0.01400000',
  'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000',
  'price': '1800.00000000',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'status': 'NEW',
  'stopPrice': '0.00000000',
  'symbol': 'ETHBUSD',
  'time': 1617387578966,
  'timeInForce': 'GTC',
  'type': 'LIMIT',
  'updateTime': 1617387578966}]
```

Comment: for item in json_message: order_ID = item['orderId']

Comment: Your string message which contains JSON is in the wrong format, its key-values should be enclosed with `"` (double-quotes) not `'` (single-quote)

Answer (score 0):

`json_message` appears to be a list with one element (the dictionary), hence the error when trying to index a list with a string.  Try `json_message = json.loads(open_stop_loss)[0]` or use a for loop.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the response, this fixed the first error but the second one still remains, any ideas? this one: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list